# Dojo 1.5.x, DateTextBox and Locale

Tags: date, internationalization, dojo, locale

I am pulling my hair out trying to make dijit.form.DateTextBox for Dojo 1.5.1 to only use one date format for validation and formatting regardless of the user's browser's locale.  Using something like this:

```
var d = new dijit.form.DateTextBox({name:n,displayedValue:v,format:{ formatLength:'short',     selector:'date',datePattern:'MM/dd/yyyy',locale:'en' }},formElement);
```

...and the browser is set to French Canadian ("fr-ca") it validates a date like "10/05/2012" as being incorrect when it isn't.  Why is it ignoring the explicit datePattern?

Sadly I have to use Dojo 1.5.1 as this is what ships with IBM Lotus Domino 8.5.3.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Alex

Comment: ...I also forgot that it's essentially that it submit the date in this format as well.  Many thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I gave this a try, I think you've mixed up "format" with "constraints."  Please see the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/DPhxq/  Seems to validate okay even in FR-CA